# Laravel datatable row details

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using a single datatable in Laravel 5.4 since it is already implemented in the Laravel framework. My datatable is using query builder to get data, for example using something like this:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <table id="services" class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Plate</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Year</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#services').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable_ser.getdata') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'plate', name: 'plate'},
            {data: 'brand', name: 'vehicle.brand'},
            {data: 'year', name: 'vehicle.year'},


        ]
    });    
});  
</script>
@stop
```

And to get it working proberly, I have to include this file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Since datatables are included in Laravel, it takes css from bootstrap, javascript from the datatables package installed in laravel.

Now, reading [row detail documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html) it is a bit unclear, how can I achieve row details in my case. What do I have to add into the code? Do I have to include some more files?

Same with other features as `Edit` or `Remove` buttons for each row. Laravel itself doesn't have documentation for datatables so it is a bit confusing what to do now. Thanks for help.

Comment: [Row Detail](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) is used when you are about to show Custom Row details. But there is another api available [DataTable Responsive](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-07-16) which does the same thing which shows rows details w.r.t screen sizes.

Comment: Im pretty sure there is many features availabe how to do row detail, but Im trying to do one using API but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So in my view, I put an ajax function to call the data.

```
 $('#pesquisarFinal').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      url = '{{ route("disciplina.criar.ano.novo",["curso" => ":id"]) }}';
      url = url.replace(":id", $("#curso").val());

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { 
           '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
           curso: $('#curso').val(),
           nivel: $('#nivel').val(),
           semestre: $('#semestre').val()
        }
      }).done(function(msg){
         oTable.clear().draw();
         oTable.rows.add(msg.data).draw();          
      });
})
```

In my controller, I did like this to call the rows to insert into the table

```
public function criarNovoAno(Request $request, Curso $curso){
        
        $curso = Curso::find($request->curso);
        $dados = Array();
        
        foreach($curso->disciplina as $item){
            $check = '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$item->pivot->id.'" class="flat atribuir"/>';
            if($request->semestre == $item->pivot->semestre->idsemestre && $request->semestre == $item->pivot->nivel->idnivel){
                array_push($dados,[$check,$item->codigo, $item->nome, $item->pivot->semestre->descricao, $item->pivot->nivel->descrico, $curso->nome]);
            }
        }      

        return response()->json(["data" => $dados]);
    }
```

in the controller, I create an array, when the loop start I create a new array for each position in the first array.

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1mo9.png)